# Envers, not inserting deletes in history tables for orphan deletes

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

We are using *NHibernate* and **Envers**. Everything works fine, but envers is not inserting audits for deleting orphans.

```
Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
```

Where can I find a good envers documentation for nhibernate?
Is it possible at all so that *evers* is doing delete entries in history tables for deleting an orphan?

```
...
entity.SomeCollection.Clear(); //Orphans will be deleted because cascade is AllDeleteOrphan.
tx.commit();
```

Best regards!

Comment: You should probably start with Google. Let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, found the answer myself.
Envers is doing inserts for orphan deletes:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

MyItem item = session.Get<MyItem>(44); //Item enthält ein Tag.

item.Tags.Clear();

tx.Commit(); 

session.Close();
```

But only if the relation end is not declared inverse.

```
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Items)
        .Table("MyItem_MyTag")
        .ParentKeyColumn("MyTagID")
        .ChildKeyColumn("MyItemID")
        .Cascade.All()
        .Inverse().LazyLoad();
```

If you want an entry non the less, then add:

nhibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change

http://envers.bitbucket.org/